# PHP Ruflin/Elastica loading without composer - Class 'Psr\Log\NullLogger' not found

Tags: php, elastica, spl-autoload-register

I have a problem with a manually loaded (without Composer) PHP library, Ruflin/Elastica. As [documentation says in include section](https://elastica.io/getting-started/installation.html#section-include) I made a loader.php file which dynamically loads the required files. It works fine, but base Client.php file throws me an error `PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: **Class 'Psr\Log\NullLogger' not found`. As I see NullLogger.php searched by loader.php file is completely missing.

The problem is with missing package PSR0 which Elastica requires. It is nonsense to load it without Composer.

What should do to make it work?

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: The problem is with missing package PSR0 which Elastica requires. It is nonsense to load it without Composer.